# Determining if SSRS Report Contains No Data from WebService

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have an application that calls off to an SSRS WebService (SSRS 2008) to run a report in the following manner:

```
SSRSService.Render(rpt, format, deviceInfo, out result, out extension, out mimetype, out encoding, out warnings, out streamids);
```

After it does this, it uses the byte[] result to create a file. The issue I am running into is that sometimes the reports do not contain any data. When this happens, I would like to abort/bypass creating the file. After calling the render method, is there a way to reliably tell if the report is contains data or not?

I know there is a property on the Tablix called NoRowsMessage, which can be set when no data comes back. Is there a way to reliably pull this out of the byte[] no matter what format the user chose for running the report? Alternatively, is there a way I can add a warning to the SSRSExecutionService.Warning[]?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer for the similar situation. Dave, did you find a work around? Let me know.

Comment: In a similar situation. Waiting for replies to the query raised by @Dave